# How to listen to focus event in CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'd like to listen to the focus event in CKEditor 5.

I thought something like this would work but the callback is never called:

```
document.querySelector("#editable");
ClassicEditor.create(el).then(editor => {
    editor.on('focus', () => {
        console.log("Focused");
    });
});
```

The editor is successfully created but the callback is not called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

The editor comes with a `FocusTracker` (and the observable [`#isFocused`](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_focustracker-FocusTracker.html#member-isFocused) property) for that purpose:

```
editor.ui.focusTracker.on( 'change:isFocused', ( evt, name, value ) => {
    console.log( 'isFocused = ', value );
} );
```

Note that `editor.ui.focusTracker.isFocused` is `true` as long as **any UI** has focus, which includes the editable but also the toolbar, floating panels, etc.

To determine the [focus](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_editableelement-EditableElement.html#member-isFocused) of the editable, i.e. when the caret is blinking and typing is possible, use this listener instead:

```
editor.editing.view.document.on( 'change:isFocused', ( evt, name, value ) => {
    console.log( 'editable isFocused =', value );
} );
```

Place one listener next to the other and play with the editor and the UI to see the difference.

Comment: Psst! I just wanted to let you know there's an [official guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/focus-tracking.html) about focus tracking in CKEditor 5 you may want to check out.