# Way to style individual instances of CKEditors?

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm trying to style the width/height (including min/max width and height) of my ckeditors. I've ran across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559354/how-to-set-the-height-of-ckeditor-5-classic-editor) (about styling `.ck-editor__editable_inline`), but the problem is that I have multiple instances of editors on a page, and want to have different heights/widths for different instances of editors.

I've tried manually hanging the minheight of the particular div with `.ck-editor__editable_inline` class through javascript (styling `editor.ui.view.editable._editableElement`), but upon focusing the editor, the styling disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I've found to approach this problem is through what is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663625/how-to-listen-to-focus-event-in-ckeditor-5) which is to apply the styling again every time the focus of the editor is altered. This results in the follow code in my case:

```js
CKEditor.PostEditor.create(e)
    .then(editor => {
        $('#submit-body-form').next().find('.ck-editor__editable_inline').addClass('post-editor-min-height');
        editor.ui.focusTracker.on('change:isFocused', (evt, name, value) => {
            $('#submit-body-form').next().find('.ck-editor__editable_inline').addClass('post-editor-min-height');
        });
    })
```